# Clearing the screen

Tags: c#, xna

SomeClass.cs

```
public void clearscreen()
{
    main.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
}
```

Why can't I clear the screen by calling on this method from another class?

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    mainMenu.MenuDraw();
    spriteBatch.Draw(cursorTexture, cursorPosition, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

The clearscreen method is being called from within mainMenu.Draw();

Comment: Before calling that method I have drawn a image to the screen. After calling the method the image is still on the screen.

Comment: are you sure you are calling this method in Draw(GameTime gametime) method.. can you show us your Draw method code..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your GraphicsDeviceManager (most likely named 'graphics') to the class and call it as so.

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your Draw method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime cGameTime) 
{
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); 
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black); 
        ....
        ....
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect your drawing method to another class you still need to use the first graphicsDevice as declared in Game1.cs (a default class name for new MonoGame project). My approach was to create another class that would hold the graphicsDevice reference in static public access. Therefore:

Game1.cs:LoadContent

```
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    Memory.spriteBatch = spriteBatch;
```

Memory.cs:

```
class Memory
{
    //monogame

    public static GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
```

Now in your redirected class, e.g. BattleModule.cs:

```
private static void DrawGeometry()
{
Memory.spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
```