# Remove items from screen on rectangle click

Tags: c#, events, xna

I've created a rectangle, that has its own class. In the class I have a delegate created, that closes the game.

Creating the delegate:

```
public event EventHandler ExitRequested = delegate { };
```

In the update method I tell when to execute it:

```
if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    ExitRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

In my main class I execute the delegate like this (the exitGame is a rectangle):

```
exitGame.ExitRequested += exitGame_ExitRequested;
```

What I'm wondering about is there a way how to remove all items from the screen? Lets say it's for a "new game" functionality. I tried to create this functionality the same way I created the exit functionality but I can't figure out how to remove the items...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451112/clearing-the-screen)

Comment: Could you post your entire Game class code? What I understand is that you are trying to reset the state of you game aka start new game?

Comment: @Juken, clearing the screen refers to setting the backbuffer/rendertarget data to a specified color which is unrelated to this post.

Comment: The code is too long, sorry. But yes, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: You could use pastebin.com to paste the entire Game class for example. I agree, posting it here is not a good idea. Anyway, this way we could better understand the issue and possibly provide a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to remove all game entities / objects in order to start a new game. Usually this is achieved by **storing entities in a collection**, and then simply removing all collection entries when a 'new game' is needed. As for entities which are not generic, such as the player, usually you just reset every member that needs to be reset; position, points etc.

Say you have a class to hold information about entities, such as enemies:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Texture2D Sprite;
    public Rectangle Bounds;

    public Entity(Texture2D Sprite, Rectangle Bounds)
    {
        this.Sprite = Sprite;
        this.Bounds = Bounds;
    }    

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //Movement code here
    }    

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Sprite,Bounds,Color.White);
    }
}
```

And you then store all entities in a collection:

```
public List<Entity> Entities = new List<Entity>();
```

You update and draw each entity by looping through the collection:

```
//In main game class
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Entity e in Entities)
        e.Update(gameTime);
}

public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Entity e in Entities)
        e.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

Then when you want to start a new game, and effectively remove all entities, you can simply remove all entries in the Entities list. (For example using `List.Clear()`, there are many ways)

Keep in mind this is an example which has not been tested, so to say. This is can be optimized, and is more to give you an idea of why collections are useful for organizing game objects / entities.